# Does ECMAscript offer any ways of constructing functions?

Tags: javascript, types, constructor

As far as I know, constructors are unable to produce functions: they can assign properties to `this`, and offer an immediate `prototype` reference for further properties that are generic and thus not instance-specific. But it's impossible to assign anything to `this` directly. Even if it were, the logical outcome would be to replace the instance with the assignment, along with its prototype chain.

From what I have read of ES6 Classes, they amount to syntax sugar for grouping constructor  declaration and prototype instantiation in a single statement.

My practical interest lies in the value of the `instanceof` operator in asserting that X conforms to the higher order description of Y without any duck-typing. In particular, duck-typing is undesirable because it relies on some kind of definition of Y which is external to Y itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit

> I'm interested in functions which are instances of other functions

In [***ECMAScript 6***](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.setprototypeof) you should be able to call [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) on a *function*, but it isn't advised and although in *JavaScript* a *Function* is an *Object* too you may end up with unexpected behaviour

```
function foo() {}
function bar() {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(bar, foo.prototype);
bar instanceof foo; // true
bar.constructor === foo; // true
```

---

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but hopefully these code examples will help you

Returning an *Object* from a function invoked with `new`

```
function Foo() {
    // a constructor
}
function Bar() {
    // another constructor
    return new Foo();
}

var b = new Bar();
b instanceof Bar; // false
b instanceof Foo; // true
```

Using [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```
function Fizz() {
    return new Function('return "Buzz";');
}
var b = Fizz();
b(); // "Buzz"
```

Invoking a *function* with a different `this` by using `call`, `apply` or `bind`

```
function hello() {
    return this;
}
hello(); // window, null or error depending on environment
hello.call({'foo': 'bar'});  // {'foo': 'bar'}
hello.apply({'foo': 'bar'}); // {'foo': 'bar'}
var b = hello.bind({'fizz': 'buzz'});
b(); // {'fizz': 'buzz'}
```

Extending a constructor

```
function Foo() {
    this.foo = 'foo';
}
Foo.prototype = {'fizz': 'buzz'};

function Bar() {
    Foo.call(this);
    this.bar = 'bar';
}
// and link in inheritance
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);

var b = new Bar();
b.bar; // "bar"
b.foo; // "foo"
b.fizz; // "buzz"

b instanceof Bar; // true
b instanceof Foo; // true
// but
Bar instanceof Foo; // false
```

Comment: These are neat little examples on how `new` and `this` can be used. I'm interested in functions which are instances of other functions, which I believe aren't possible.

Comment: @Barney not sure if this is helpful but have a look at my edit

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks! I'll have a play around and try to set up some tests to qualify what I was after in the first place and how 'adviseable' it is… ;)

Comment: Paul, works a charm. I can now type-check functions (in very few environments, and at significant cost). Thanks!

Comment: @Barney you may want to set the prototype as `Object.create(foo.prototype)` to enable `bar` to have inheritance not inherited by `foo`. Also `instanceof` isn't the only way to have checks, you can add your own properties to functions just as with any other object, and it costs much less. (For it to be out-the-way, look into enumerability ;) )

Comment: To be honest it's not so much a practical issue as an experiment in type assertion. I'm investigating possibilities for creating functions which can be said to conform to certain expectation at run-time, eg is this an `eventHandler` or a `getterSetter` etc.

Comment: `function foo () {}; Object.defineProperty(foo, '_type', {value: 'fizz'}); foo._type = 'buzz'; foo._type;
// "fizz"`

Answer (score 0):

Constructors **can** construct functions. If your constructor returns an object, the object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole `new` expression.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

As functions are objects, you can return them just as well from your constructor as shown here:

```
function Shout(text) {
  return function () {
    alert(text);
  };
 }

shout1 = new Shout('hola');
shout2 = new Shout('eeee');

shout1();  // hola
shout2();  // eeee
```

Comment: I think the asker's problem with this is that `shout1 instanceof Shout; // false`

Comment: Functions can indeed return functions, but as soon as `return` is invoked, `this` becomes lost and it becomes impossible to assert that `shout1` has any relation to `Shout`. Using `new` in this context is misleading as `Shout` is a 'factory' which produces an arbitrary output.